# how to parse out file name and import the data into csv files using shellscript?

Tags: matlab, shell, csv

I have a Matlab program output some data into filenames for example a filename look like

```
Temperature_10_Volumn_5.dat
```

The file is empty inside, but I need to parse out 10 and 5. I have 1000 files like this. What would be the easiest shellscript to parse out the numbers and write them to a csv file such that Matlab can read the csv file and plot the graph? Thanks!

Comment: you want to make a file that contains 10;5 for that exemple is that right ?

Comment: can 10;5 be easily read by matlab though?

Comment: sure you can do that from Matlab but I dont understand what the point of all these files. Do they actually contain values (csv values ?). Do you want to append these values to one file according to these index (10 5 etc...) or is 10 the actual temperature data and 5 the actual volumn data ?

Comment: 10 and 5 are the actual data, I know it's a stupid method... this is a very simplified version of what we are doing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the script that will print all your values in a single file with values separated by ";"

Usage is :

```
parse_file.sh /home/user/your_dir_to_files output.csv

#!/bin/bash
#title         :parse_file.sh
#description   :parse file name into a single file
#author        :Bertrand Martel
#date          :13/08/2015

file_list=`ls $1`

IFS=$'\n'     #line delimiter

#empty your output file
cp /dev/null "$2"

for i in $file_list; do

    #get temperature between _ and _
    temperature=`echo $i | awk -v FS="([_]|[_])" '{print $2}'`

    #remove everything before Volumn
    second_part=`echo $i | sed 's/.*Volumn//'`
    
    #get volume between _ and .
    volume=`echo $second_part | awk -v FS="([_]|[.])" '{print $2}'`

    new_line="$temperature;$volume"

    #append to file
    echo $new_line >> "$2"
done

cat "$2"
```

I created a gist with the file https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/fd68c0373af35eaba934

I assume you only have the so called files in you directory output